# Scheduled class is not executing batch class

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I've set up a schedulable class that calls a batch class, but when I run the test class, it successfully calls the schedulable class, but the batch class is never called.

What am I missing?

Here is the test class:

```
@isTest
public class DDParticipantCampaignTest {
    public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 15 3 ? 2022'; 
    static testMethod void testParticipant(){   

    Id DDEventCampaignRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('DD Events') == null ? null : Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('DD Events').getRecordTypeId();
    Id DDDonationRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('DD Donations') == null ? null : Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('DD Donations').getRecordTypeId();
    Datetime yesterday = Datetime.now().addDays(-1);
    Campaign c = TestHarness.createCampaign(date.today(), 0);
    c.RecordTypeId = DDEventCampaignRecordTypeId;
    c.Name = 'Test DD Campaign';
    insert c;
    Test.setCreatedDate(c.Id, yesterday);
    update c;

    Contact p = new Contact(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'Participant', Email = 'test@participant.com');
    p.DonorDrive_ID_walklikemadd__c = '123456';
    insert p;
    Test.setCreatedDate(p.Id, yesterday);
    update p;

    Contact d = TestHarness.createContact('Donor');
    d.FirstName = 'Test';
    d.DonorDrive_ID_walklikemadd__c = '12345';
    insert d;
    Test.setCreatedDate(d.Id, yesterday);
    update d;

    Opportunity o = TestHarness.createOpportunity(DDDonationRecordTypeId, c, d);
    o.ddrive__Participant_First_Name__c = p.FirstName;
    o.ddrive__Participant_Last_Name__c = p.LastName;
    o.ddrive__Participant_Email__c = p.Email;
    o.StageName = 'Closed Won';
    o.CloseDate = date.today().addDays(-1);
    insert o;

    Test.setCreatedDate(o.Id, yesterday);
    update o;

    List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT createdDate FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: o.Id];

    System.debug('Opportunity name: ' + o.Name);
    System.debug('Participant name: ' + o.ddrive__Participant_First_Name__c + ' ' + o.ddrive__Participant_Last_Name__c);
    System.debug('Opportunity last modified: ' + o.LastModifiedDate);
    System.debug('Opportunity created: ' + opps[0].CreatedDate);

    Test.startTest();
    String jobId = System.schedule('ScheduledApexTest',
        CRON_EXP, 
        new DDParticipantCampaignSched()); 
    Test.stopTest();
    List <CampaignMember> camp = new List <CampaignMember>();
    String contactLastName;
    String campaignName;
    For(CampaignMember cm : [SELECT Id FROM CampaignMember]){
        contactLastName = cm.Contact.LastName;
        campaignName = cm.Campaign.Name;
        if(contactLastName == 'Participant' && campaignName == 'Test DD Campaign'){
            camp.add(cm);
        }
    }
    System.assertEquals(camp.size(), 1);
}

}
```

Here is the Schedulable class, which the test is calling successfully:

```
global class DDParticipantCampaignSched implements Schedulable{
   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
      DDParticipantCampaignBatch part = new DDParticipantCampaignBatch(); 
      database.executeBatch(part,50);
   }

}
```

And here is the batch class, which is not being called:

```
global class DDParticipantCampaignBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
   global database.Querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

    String query = 'SELECT Id '+
                   ' FROM Opportunities'+
                   ' WHERE (ddrive__Participant_First_Name__c != null'+
                   ' AND ddrive__Participant_Last_Name__c != null'+
                   ' AND CampaignId != null';

    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);      
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Opportunity> scope) {  
    if(scope.size() > 0){
        DDParticipantCampaign.createCampaignMembers(scope);      
    }           
   }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Test.stopTest()` causes all functionality already enqueued to run synchronously. However, that just causes the scheduled job to fire and enqueue the batch. Since your batch wasn't enqueued when you called `Test.stopTest()`, it does *not* run synchronously.